# Permission denied error for initdb (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I'm attempting to set up PostgreSQL 9.3 on Debian without root access. Following [this guide](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/06/installing-postgresql-without-root.html) I successfully compiled and installed it into /home/.local. However, when I run `/home/.local/bin/initdb -D /home/.local/data/`, it displays the following.

```
fbbgsa@web1:~/.local$ initdb -D ~/.local/data
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "fbbgsa".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /home/.local/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 10
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /home/.local/data/base/1 ... FATAL:  shmat(id=18808835) failed: Permission denied
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/home/.local/data"
```

It may be worth noting that before running this command, the data folder's permissions were `drwxr-xr-x`, but appear to have changed to `drwxr-----` afterwards.

Comment: That's weird, because it means that PostgreSQL was able to create a shared memory segment with `shmget`, but then failed to connect to it with `shmat`. Look where your `tmpfs` is mounted - do you see any shared memory segments there?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but `dt -T` gives me 
`none         tmpfs   104526048  76886752  27639296  74% /dev/shm` 
and `/dev/shm` seems to be entirely empty

Comment: I would run initdb with `strace -f -o /tmp/trace initdb ...` to create a trace file `/tmp/trace`. Then look at the trace file and see what happens with the `shmget` and `shmat` call.

Comment: Apparently I can't run strace, it returns `strace: ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...): Permission denied` no matter what options I put in, appears to be some security thing that I can't change without root access. Are there any other ways to see what `shmget` and `shmat` are doing?

Comment: Not that I know of - On the Linuxen I know running `strace` as normal user is no problem. Do you have Selinux enabled? Maybe ask your system administrator.